# Registering a singleton via SimpleInjector and return the same instance, for different interfaces it implements

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

Imagine I have the below:

```cs
public interface IocInterface1 { }

public interface IocInterface2 { }

public class IocImpl : IocInterface1, IocInterface2 { }
```

I would like that if I try to get any instance of the above classes/interfaces via IoC, I get the exact same instance, not one singleton per type.  Example, `b1` and `b2` below should be true:

```cs
_container.RegisterSingle<IocInterface1, IocImpl>();
_container.RegisterSingle<IocInterface2, IocImpl>();
_container.RegisterSingle<IocImpl, IocImpl>();

var test1 = _container.GetInstance<IocInterface1>();
var test2 = _container.GetInstance<IocInterface2>();
var test3 = _container.GetInstance<IocImpl>();

bool b1 = test1 == test2;
bool b2 = test2 == test3;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to register a multiple types with the same registration then you will need a singleton registration object for your implementation type `IocImpl`.

Then you need to use `AddRegistration` to add this registration for the different services: `IocInterface1`, `IocInterface2` etc.:

```cs
var _container = new Container();
var registration =
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IocImpl, IocImpl>(_container);

_container.AddRegistration(typeof(IocImpl), registration);
_container.AddRegistration(typeof(IocInterface1), registration);
_container.AddRegistration(typeof(IocInterface2), registration);
```

as described in the documenation: [Register multiple interfaces with the same implementation](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to#Register-Multiple-Interfaces-With-The-Same-Implementation)

Alternatively, you can also make a mapping using delegates:

```
_container.RegisterSingle<IocImpl>();
_container.RegisterSingle<IocInterface1>(() => container.GetInstance<IocImpl>());
_container.RegisterSingle<IocInterface2>(() => container.GetInstance<IocImpl>());
```

In most cases both examples are functionally equivalent, but the former is preferred.

Comment: This looks good for what I need - However, does it cater for `container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric()` as well?  The reason is I have an assembly scanner which scans all types which I decorate with a custom attribute I created `[IocComponent]`, and this also caters for open-generics.

Comment: The `RegisterSingleOpenGeneric` works a little bit different because it is creating registration on the fly in the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event... I have to think about how it can be done without replaciting the logic of the `RegisterSingleOpenGeneric` method. But I think you should ask this is a follow up question where you specify the details of how the scanning works and how it tries to register the generic types.

Comment: I agree with @nemesv: please ask a new question with these details. This answer is correct. +1 for that.

Comment: @Steven I've also found the "delegate solution" I was just not sure how preferred to reference the `container` inside the creator function.

Comment: I've managed to solve it in the scanner I had, where I'm doing the 'normal' logic when I meet a `GenericTypeDefinition`, and the logic as per your answer here, so this is perfect for my requirements - thanks! :)